# Next JS при статичном деплое не видит оптимизированные картинки в формате WEBP

Tags: изображения, развертывание, next.js

Для оптимизации картинок использую библиотеку next-image-export-optimizer. Локально все работает как надо, но после деплоя, при загрузке оптимизированных картинок, вылетает ошибка 404 и загружаются изначальные картинки.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "next-ssg-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "export": "next build && next-image-export-optimizer"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "14.1.0",
    "next-image-export-optimizer": "^1.12.3",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

next.config.mjs

```
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: false,
    output: "export",

    images: {

        loader: "custom",
        imageSizes: [16, 32, 48, 64, 96, 128, 256, 384],
        deviceSizes: [640, 750, 828, 1080, 1200, 1920, 2048, 3840],

    },
    transpilePackages: ["next-image-export-optimizer"],
    env: {
        nextImageExportOptimizer_imageFolderPath: "public",
        nextImageExportOptimizer_exportFolderPath: "out",
        nextImageExportOptimizer_quality: "75",
        nextImageExportOptimizer_storePicturesInWEBP: "true",
        nextImageExportOptimizer_exportFolderName: "nextImageExportOptimizer",

        nextImageExportOptimizer_remoteImageCacheTTL: "0",
    },

};
export default nextConfig;
```

page.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ExportedImage from "next-image-export-optimizer";
import testPictureStatic from "../../../public/pngwing.com.png";



const Page = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            PAGE_ONE
            <ExportedImage src={testPictureStatic} alt="Static Image" />;
        </div>
    );
};

export default Page;
```

[image: Загрузка картинки на localhost]

[image: Загрузка картинки на хостинге]